# How do I Find the value of a & b that makes the function continuous?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I'm stumped on this problem. I took a picture of my work to save the hassle of typing it all.

Can someone please help me find the values of a and b?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $6 \times (-1)^{-1}= -6$, not $-1/6= -6^{-1}$, as you have it.

You just have to solve $6 (-1)^{-1} = a(-1)+b$ and $9(1/2)^{-1}=a(1/2)+b$.  You should be able to finish it from here.

Comment: I tried that but I'm getting a=18 and b=9?

Comment: Never mind. I made a dumb mistake. My 6's and b's look a lot alike lol. Thanks! I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

For a function to be continuous it needs to have the same value as where it switches between statements, here $-1$ and $1/2$.

The first 2 equations must be equal at $x = -1$ so that it's continuous. Simplifying that's $-b = -a + b$. Then for the next two, $a/2 + b = 2a$ where $x = 2$. Using these equations you should be able to solve for $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

To show the function is continuous at $c$, you need that both the right and left limits as $x \to c$ are equal to the function value at $c$.  So, set $\lim_{x \to -1^-} 6x^{-1} = a(-1)+b$ (I think that you've written a $6x^{-1}$, not a $bx^{-1}$, but it's hard to tell).  Then do the same on the other side: $\lim_{x \to 1/2^+} 9x^{-1} = a(1/2)+b$.  You should get a system of equations you can then solve.